# typescript Intellisense is not showing the type of the variable or taking me to the definition

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I usually use javascript, when hovering on an import or variable name it shows you the type and any documentation.

when clicking on a variable or import it will take you to the definition even if it is in `node_modules` or in core-js at `C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Microsoft/TypeScript ...`

as shown on the first photo,

on javascript:

[image]

while on typescript file, this is not working as shown on this photo:

[image]

how to make this work?

I have all `@types` installed. but it's either problem with `tsconfig`  or I need to install some sort of extension but don't which one is exactly what I need.

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

before you delete the question, I tried to get the answer from the vs-code website, but no response.

Comment: Did you also install the types? npm install --save-dev @types/express

Comment: yes I did, the problem is with all variables not just express

Comment: have you tried using import statements instead of requires?

Comment: import statements didn't work also

Comment: Can you try reloading your VS code window or CMD + Shift + P and then restart ts server? Sometimes VS code doesn't get TS updates so you need to restart it.

Comment: I hope your ts config file name is `tsconfig.json` not `tsconfig`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @tHeSiD

using `import` statements instead of `require` solved the problem.